# Load files from Plugins directory

Tags: php, directory, directory-listing

I need to load index.php file from each of the plugins' folders. There is the main folder "plugins" and inside there are, sub folders (plugins) e.g blog, members etc. Inside each plugin folder there is an index.php file which i need to load. How can i load the directory and search for these files. The plugin folders are not static and might change.

What i have tried

```
    $dir_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($this->plugin_dir);
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    // could use CHILD_FIRST if you so wish

    foreach ($iterator as $file) {
        echo $file, "\n";
    }
```

and..the glob function (which didn't help much

```
$list = glob('index.php', GLOB_BRACE);
    foreach($list as $files){
        echo $files;
    }
    print_r($list);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a double listing way..

```
private function loadPlugins(){
    $dir = array_diff(scandir($this->plugin_dir), array('..', '.'));
    foreach($dir as $ds){
        $list = glob($this->plugin_dir.'/'.$ds.'/index.php', GLOB_BRACE);
        foreach($list as $files){
            require $files;
        }
    }
}
```